# Rounding in XERO API integration

Tags: php

I'm integrating XERO API to my solution. Here i want to round the values to 4 decimal digits, default rounding they are providing is 2 decimal points
They are saying that we can do 4 decimal places by adding the querystring parameter unitdp=4  to our request. i tried like this  by passing "?unitdp=4" in $param

```
$post_body = trim(substr($post_body, (stripos($post_body, ">")+1) ));
        if ( in_array( $name, $valid_post_methods ) ) {
            $param="?unitdp=4";
            $xero_url = self::ENDPOINT . $method.$param;

            $req  = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token( $this->consumer, $this->token, 'POST',$xero_url, array('xml'=>$post_body) );
            $req->sign_request($this->signature_method , $this->consumer, $this->token);
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $xero_url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req->to_postdata() );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $req->to_header());
        } else {
            $xero_url = self::ENDPOINT . $method;
            $req  = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token( $this->consumer, $this->token, 'PUT',$xero_url );
            $req->sign_request($this->signature_method , $this->consumer, $this->token);
            $xml = $post_body;
            $fh  = fopen('php://memory', 'w+');
            fwrite($fh, $xml);
            rewind($fh);
            $ch = curl_init($req->to_url());
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fh);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, strlen($xml));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $xero_response = curl_exec($ch);
```

But i'm getting error response from them. Please help me if anyone faced the same issue while integration XERO API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xero support api library for php.
Why don't you use it?

Then you can easily add the `unitdp` param to the action urls.

For instance, if you use the xero api library, the sample code to request an action likes below.

```
$xeroObj->request('METHOD', $xeroObj->url('Sample Action', 'core'), $extra_params);
```

You can pass the unitdp param as the `$extra_params` parameter.
eg: `array('unitdp' => 4')`

Comment: I was using the old library, that is not in development now this one https://github.com/XeroAPI/PHP-Xero, so i need to use the new library?

Comment: can you tell how i can pass in the old one. i used like this to get Response form XERO $invoice_result = $xero->Invoices( $new_invoice );

Comment: I have never used the old library. Is it difficult to use the new library on your system?